# Firebase Storage Emulator rules not working

Tags: ios, firebase-storage, emulation, rules, firebase-tools

My app is working just fine but when I use the Firebase emulators, I have a problem with the Storage rules not being obeyed.
I have downloaded the `storage.rules` file and it is in the same directory as the `firebase-json` file.  The Emulator suite launches just fine and I can see that the Storage emulator is working.
However, when I try to upload an image (as I do in the live app) I get an error.

`Error while uploading file:  Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access gs://my-stuff-7796d.appspot.com/Profiles/0ye7psTQA4xR6DfjZRXjjtCWKyPw.jpg." UserInfo={object=Profiles/0ye7psTQA4xR6DfjZRXjjtCWKyPw.jpg, ResponseBody={"error":{"code":403,"message":"Permission denied. No WRITE permission."}}, bucket=my-stuff-7796d.appspot.com, data={length = 74, bytes = 0x7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2263 6f646522 ... 73696f6e 2e227d7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8, NSLocalizedDescription=User does not have permission to access gs://my-stuff-7796d.appspot.com/Profiles/0ye7psTQA4xR6DfjZRXjjtCWKyPw.jpg., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=403}`

The storage.rules are:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Again, running against the live Firebase works just fine and the rules are obeyed.
Here is my **firebase.json** file

```
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I launch my app, this is the code I initialize after call FirebaseApp.configure

```
Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9099)
Storage.storage().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9199)
let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
settings.host = "localhost:8080"
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
settings.isSSLEnabled = false
Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
```

What am I missing, or is this a bug?

Comment: Further to his issue, If I manually add an image to the Storage bucket in the emulator console, I can read from my app.  The app will just not upload the image, though it does in the live environment.
If, after having successfully manually uploaded and read the image from the app, I try to upload a new one from the app, the upload fails, but the previous one that I had manually uploaded gets removed.

Comment: One more update.
I just updated to Firebase-tools 9.20.0 and now when I try to upload an image, the simulators just crash. :(

Comment: At its present state the Firebase Storage emulator seems to be somewhat unreliable. Prone to crashes or behaving in an unpredictable manner.

Comment: I have filed a bug report and it has been verified so waiting for an update

Comment: @StewartLynch Could you link to the bug report you filed please?

Comment: oops.  Sorry @joshpetit I missed that comment. This is what I found in my inbox regarding that bug report Case 10151612: Storage WRITE rules not being recognized in Storage.rules in Emulator Suite

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. It seems to have been resolved for me in version 11.8.0. As a temporary workaround, I resorted to allowing all reads/writes so that I wasn't having to use my production environment and pay for usage. Not an ideal solution, but it unblocked me.

But for those who might be having similar issues, try updating to the latest firebase-tools:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Be sure to address any issues with:

```
npm audit fix
```

Or make the following change to the storage.rules file:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```